# TableCell Data passing to another UIViewController

Tags: sql, swift, uitableview

I have a Table which populates data from SQL into TableCells. When i click on a Cell, I want the data of **only** that particular cell to be passed to a different UIViewController. Data includes Strings. How do I go about this?

Comment: what is your cell selection type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it easy for future searchers to reach this answer-

## Transferring data between UITableViewController to UIViewController

#### Method 1- using storyboard (less code)

Starting scene-

**Table View Controller** (embedded in UINavigationController) - that's the first ViewController we'll see when we'll open the app, we want him to transfer data to our Destination View Controller

**Destination View Controller**- that's the ViewController we'll reach after selecting a cell.

You can see in the following GIF that I've set a segue from our TableViewCell to Destination View Controller, the segue's identifier is `toDestination` (can't see the **blue line when dragging**? hold **ctrl** while doing that)

[image: Setting up segue]

That's how your storyboard scene should look like-

(don't forget to set your cell's reuse identifier so you can use it later in code)

[image: starting scene]
Now lets dive into code:

In our TableViewController we write this function:

```
// Here we're transfering the data we want to our DestinationViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController{

        if let pressedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            // passed string is just some variable I've declared on DestinationViewController
            destinationVC.passedString = dataHolder[pressedIndexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

When did you even call this function?-
 I didn't call it, it's being called automatically because I've set a segue between our cell to our DestinationViewController using our storyboard (remember the starting scene?...), now every time the user presses that cell a segue starts automatically and this function is being called

Our DestinationViewController side looks like that-

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

      var passedString: String!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          label.text = passedString
       }
}
```

We're done, here's the final result
[image]

Full code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

   let dataHolder = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return dataHolder.count }


   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       // change "cell" to your cell's reuse identifier
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

       cell.textLabel?.text = dataHolder[indexPath.row]

       return cell
   }

   // Here we're transfering the data we want to our DestinationViewController
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController{

           if let pressedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{

               destinationVC.passedString = dataHolder[pressedIndexPath.row]
           }
       }
    }
}
```

And on the other side:

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

      var passedString: String!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          label.text = passedString
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell like this

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var yourData: CustomData? // You can put your data here as you want, you can also have three different variables for your data

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // Initialization code
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

After that in function cellForRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // Here you can set data of your cell as you want
    cell.yourData = // Put your data

    return cell
}
```

And then you can pass your data using `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell: CustomCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    let yourData = selectedCell.yourData
    // Here you can perform a segue or you can present a ViewController and pass your data
    ....
}
```