# Get value from JSON and pass to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, pass-data

I've to get value from my JSON and pass this string to a variable in the second View. So, my problem it's not get value from JSON because I did it. How I can do it. I've just tried prepare (for segue) and other code but any of thats worked. Do you have an advice for me?

I hope I have been clearer. Sorry.
1) [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGCL.png)
2) [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1yFZ.png)

Comment: post how you navigate push /segue/present and  how you send the data ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I cancelled all because doesn't work

Comment: use prepare for segue

Comment: @canister_exister Just tried.
                    self.titolo = list["title"] as! String
                    self.descrizione = list["tagline"] as! String
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home", sender: self)


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: Any?) {
        var vc = segue.destination as! Home
        vc.nomeatt = self.titolo!
    }

Comment: vc.nomeatt??? what is that?

Comment: @canister_exister Yeah sorry. nomeatt = title so: 
vc.title = self.title!

Comment: class SecondView: UIViewController  or class Home: UIViewController ?

Comment: @canister_exister in the First View

Comment: You have problem with your class name

Comment: @canister_exister wait now i explain you all. I confused you

Comment: What about to add code when you try to switch to another VC and your prepare for segue?

Comment: @canister_exister like that:
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is Home
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? Home
            vc?.titleHome = "Test"
        }
    }

Comment: @canister_exister ok i did some test and now i know why it's not working. But i don't know how to resolve it. The problem is that betwen LoginController and Home Controller i have a Navigation Controller. file:///Users/stefanoabbruzzese/Desktop/Schermata%202018-12-06%20alle%2017.16.58%20(2).png

Comment: There are tons of tutorials for this online, you may take a look on this post- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53540610/5758873

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Home View Controller identifier") as! SecondView
homeViewController.title = self.title
homeViewController.description = self.description
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: His problem that he is trying to pass data to `SecondView` view controller but he use wrong class name `Home`

Comment: If you create a segue from first to second and use prepare for segue to set description and title, that should work. Note: why do you make them IUO and not pure optional ?

Comment: @VladM.  Look for my last comment for canister